# Breaking a while loop without using break statement

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem**

How can I stop the loop from asking "Input string" again without using break? Thanks.

**Code**

```
# Remove Break
def main():
    inp = 0
    while inp <= 0:
        inp = int(input("Enter Number: "))
        if inp > 0:
            string = ""
            while string != "you" or string != "me":
                string = input("Input string: ")
                if string == "you":
                    stringYou(inp)
                    break
                elif string == "me":
                    stringMe(inp)
                    break

def stringYou(inp):
    sentence = "I love You"
    print(sentence * inp)
def stringMe(inp):
    sentence = "You love Me"
    print(sentence * inp)
main()
```

Comment: What is wrong with using break? You might also want to let the user know if inp <= 0 and use `while s not in ("you" , "me")` so the loop ends if the user enters either string

Answer (score 0):

```
while string != "you" or string != "me":
```

The condition here is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) meaning it will always be true.

There are three interesting cases for your variable `string` here:

1. `string` is equal to `"you"`. The first condition `string != "you"` is obviously false. The second however isn’t: `string != "me"`. `string` is `"you"` which is not equal to `"me"`. So `false or true` gives you `true`.
2. `string` is equal to `"me"`. With the same reasoning, except in the opposite order, we get `true or false` which is also `true`.
3. `string` is something else. Both the subconditions are true, so `true or true` gives `true`.

So the condition is always true, and the while condition never stops on its own. So you have to break in order to get out of it.

The fix is to simply fix your conditions so that they make sense and the loop properly ends on its own:

```
while string != "you" and string != "me":
```

Note the `and`: Now, the loop only continues when `string` is *neither* `"you"` nor `"me"`. This is equivalent to your break logic where you stopped the iteration when the string became either of those strings.

So it now looks like this:

```
string = ''
while string != "you" and string != "me":
    string = input("Input string: ")
    if string == "you":
        stringYou(inp)
    elif string == "me":
        stringMe(inp)
```